# Order of before_action with Rails and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my app users can embed forms through iframes in other websites. To do so they can specify 'form settings' in a table like e. g. background-color of the form. In this table they also can specify if a user who fills out the form has to be signed in or not.

Two types of authentication methods exist:

1. User has to login via Devise (auth_id == 1)
2. User has not to login (auth_id == 2)

**Therefore my controller looks like:**

```
class MyController < ApplicationController  
  before_action :load_form_settings
  before_action :authenticate_user!, if: @settings.auth_id == 1
  ...

  private
  def load_form_settings
    @settings = Formsetting.find_by(:form_id => params[:form_id])
  end

end
```

However, it says that `@settings` is Nil. It seems like the running `:load_form_settings` before `:authenticate_user!` does not have an effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the full power of ActiveRecord `Formsetting.find_by_form_id params[:form_id]`. `@settings.auth_id == 1` — is too much to know for your controller. Create a method in `Formsetting` smth like `need_authentication?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if: -> { @settings.auth_id == 1 }`

`before_action` is a class method. It adds a new callback to the array of callbacks for the instance methods of the `MyController`. These callbacks will be executed when you call instance methods from a controller.

`@settings.auth_id == 1` is an expression. It executes at the time of adding a callback to the array. You need to pass a symbol or a proc if you want it to be executed at the time of callback execution.

Comment: undefined method `auth_id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Are you sure that `@settings = Formsetting.find_by(:form_id => params[:form_id])` does not nil?

Comment: yes. i do <%= @settings.auth_id %> in my form view to check and it says "1"

Comment: View is not enough. Add `p @settings` after `@settings = Formsetting.find_by(:form_id => params[:form_id])` and paste the ouptut.

Comment: #<Formsetting id: 54, form_name: "Test Form", form_description: "", created_at: "2018-01-19 17:41:37", updated_at: "2018-01-19 17:41:37", recipes_count: 0, access_token: "f45bc88d-d693-422a-9867-1a2662bc3671", widget_forms_count: 1, locale_id: 2, customer_id: 12, auth_id: 1, codeset_id: nil>

Comment: everything fine. auth_id is there ;)

Comment: And your controller looks like: `before_action :load_form_settings  before_action :authenticate_user!, if: -> { @settings.auth_id == 1 }`?

Comment: Ok ... I copied & pasted your code from the comment - now it works. I don't know why, because I am sure that I had this before. Maybe there was some bad typo I didn't realize. However, thanks a lot for your help!!